# Which virtualization software should i use?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, virtualization, hyper-v

i need to create a lab with free tools. In this lab there will be the three computers (1. Ubuntu server, 2. Client on Windows 7, 3. Attacker on Kali Linux). Which virtualization Software will be the best for this lab? I think there are three options:

1. VMware Player
2. Hyper-V
3. VirtualBox

[image: Virtual topology]

**What functionality i need:**

1. I need to create virtual LAN between virtual computers with **virtual switch**
2. I need separate virtual LAN and host internet connectivity (Virtual computers should connect just other computers on virtual LAN network)
3. I need to protect virtual drives on these three computers against saving changes (people can change settings on computers, but after reboot every computer will have default setting)

I think that Hyper-V could be the solution, but **host system will be Windows 7**. Do you have any idea which software should i use to create this lab? I have just brief experience with virtualization, i will be glad for any advice. Thanks Matthew.

Comment: Hyper-V does not work on Windows 7 or any prior client SKUs. Microsoft started including Hyper-V in Client SKUs starting from Windows 8 in Pro and Enterprise editions. Server SKUs did have Hyper-V since Windows Server 2008 AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer your question based on my experience.

1. I need to create virtual LAN between virtual computers with virtual switch >> all virtualization software has built in virtual switch.
2. Virtual computers should connect just other computers on virtual LAN network >> this one can be achieved using 'Internal Network' mode in virtual box.
3. people can change settings on computers, but after reboot every computer will have default setting >> I don't really know about how to do it automatically, but virtual box does have interesting feature called 'snapshot' which allows you to save a virtual machine state and restore it with ease (GUI). You can read it more here : http://www.howtogeek.com/150258/how-to-save-time-by-using-snapshots-in-virtualbox/

Hope this can help you man.

Answer (score 0):

Virtualbox has great connectivity with networks, this is verifiably doable. Per the other tools, I am not sure.